# How to override font used for bold in Safari?

Tags: css, safari

I have an application that embeds WebKit and lets me customize its appearance via CSS.  It's using `font-weight: bold;` in several places.  I want to substitute the medium variant of the font in place of the bold variant, which I find too thick.  The following works in Chrome/Mac and Firefox/Mac, but not Safari/Mac:

```css
/* Demonstrating with Avenir, which comes with macOS. */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Foo';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Avenir-Light');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Foo';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: local('Avenir-Medium');
}

.foo {
  font-family: 'Foo';
}

.control {
  font-family: 'Avenir';
}

.control.normal {
  /* Should be light. */
  font-weight: 100;
}

.control.bold {
  /* Should be medium. */
  font-weight: 500;
}

.foo.normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.foo.bold {
  /* NOTE: I cannot change this value, it must remain bold. */
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Rest of this is just to make the
   example easier to look at.  */

html {
  /* Easier to see */
  font-size: 200%;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>"Foo" font</th>
  <th>"Avenir" font</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="foo normal">Lorem ipsum</td>
  <td class="control normal">Lorem ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="foo bold">Lorem ipsum</td>
  <td class="control bold">Lorem ipsum</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

(If you prefer, same at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t6jupywo/19/)

Chrome (correct):
[image: chrome]

Firefox (correct):
[image: firefox]

Safari (**incorrect**):
[image: safari]

1. Why doesn't this work in Safari?  (I'm guessing "it's a bug [that has been around for twenty years]".)
2. What should I do instead, I assuming I can't/won't `s/font-weight: bold;/font-weight: 500;/g` all over my CSS?

Comment: Something I notice is that you're using `font-weight: bold;` for your Foo font, but `font-weight: 500;` for your Avenir font. I'll change it in the fiddle and see if anything happens.

Comment: Changing it in the fiddle certainly did something! See the changed version here https://jsfiddle.net/t6jupywo/22

Comment: You might want to keep in mind that macOS(iOS/etc.) has bolder fonts on purpose; users are actually used to and therefore likely prefer these bolder fonts.

Comment: @Jan, *"you might want to keep in mind that"* this has nothing to do with user preference, nor with what device or software manufacturers happen to believe about user preference. iOS users should not be deprived by their devices of the privilege of seeing the published content exactly as the content publisher (or any other person designated by them) decided it should be seen in order to represent the brand/product. You're seriously wrong on this one.

Comment: Nah, I completely agree with you. But what you should understand is that macOS people willfully opted into this boldness.

Comment: @JBDouble05 Sorry if it wasn't clear, I'm trying to redefine what weight gets chosen for `font-weight: bold`, specifically I want to remap it to the medium font, which is what you get with `font-weight: 500`.  So I'm showing `font-weight: bold` for Foo because I want it to use the same medium weight you get when explicitly using `font-weight: 500`.  Make sense?  Let me know if I can clarify further.